Proof for Inner Product for a Special Case
If we have an inner product defined as $ \langle A,B \rangle  = Tr(A ^\dagger B)$ , how do i prove that this is indeed an inner product for linear operators $A$ and $B$. Generally I know how to prove this using the three required properties of an inner product, but I am struggling to solve this since for my purpose, the way the trace is defined is as follows:
$$Tr(uv^\dagger) = \langle v,u \rangle, \quad u,v \in V$$
Here $v^\dagger$ is the adjoint operator such that it is the adjoint of the linear operator $v$ such that $v \colon \mathbb{C} \to V$.
More precisely: $v^\dagger(u) = \langle v,u \rangle v$.
Note: $V$ is a vector space here and assume we are working in $L(V)$
Also, some of these details are also blurry to me, I learned linear algebra from Axler's books and while he does teach mostly with the use of linear operators instead of matrix representationns and such, this type of notation and these definitions really do not make much intuitive sense to me. Any help is appreciated, I am not reallly looking for solutions, just hints.

Note that the trace is defined as a linear operator over $L(V)$ satisfying that property. Otherwise, we wouldn't be able to say what $\operatorname{tr}(A)$ is for an operator $A \in L(V)$.

I would recommend that you use/prove the following as facts to prove that this is an inner product: $\operatorname{tr}(AB) = \operatorname{tr}(BA)$, $\operatorname{tr}(A^\dagger) = \overline{\operatorname{tr}(A)}$, $\operatorname{tr}(A^\dagger A) \geq 0$.

You can also use the more standard definition of the trace (which one can prove is equivalent to the one you were given): if ${e_1,\dots,e_n}$ is an orthonormal basis of $V$, then $\operatorname{tr}(A) = \sum_{j=1}^n \langle e_j, Ae_j\rangle $

So for the first comment, you are saying I should consider that trace is a linear operator, and that the inner product defined by the trace is indeed an inner product, and then apply it for $A ^\dagger B$?

With the first comment, I was saying that the definition of the trace that you gave is incorrect. You specified what the trace of an operator of the form $uv^\dagger$ was, but did not specify what the trace does for other linear operators. But yes, the linearity of the trace will be important here

I apologize for unclarity of the statements or notation in my question, I am actually adapting this question directly from a question that I found in some university notes and while I do not want to say anything negative about the member of faculty themselves, I realized that the reason why I was confused about this question was precisely what you just stated. Thank you for your help regardless.

You have nothing to apologize for, I'm glad that you found my comment helpful. It is often the case that addressing a problem really amounts to correcting assumptions underlying the question being asked, which is why it's so important that you provided the context that you did. And you're welcome.
